# Why is there space between the parallelogram-divs?

Tags: html, css, margin

I've made a few parallelograms in a row like that, but there is some space between them. I want to remove that space. `margin-left: -1px;` works, but I'm afraid that it's a bad solution to this problem.

[image]

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rw40ugq1/

Here is the code:

```css
body {
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parallelogram {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 85px;
    transform: skew(20deg);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parallelogram"></div>
    <div class="parallelogram"></div>
    <div class="parallelogram"></div>
    <div class="parallelogram"></div>
    <div class="parallelogram"></div>
    <div class="parallelogram"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: subpixel rendring issue .. I see whitespace between all of them (change the zoom level and it will be different)

Comment: Which space are you talking about? Can you highlight it using an image, please?

Comment: @Aditya I added an image.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to use a pseudo, e.g. `.button::before {
    content: " ";
    left:-1px;
    top:0;
    right:-1px;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
}`

Comment: what's you goal? the layout you want to achieve. There is many way to visually obtain what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a small outline:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 85px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  outline:0.1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be the width of the parallelogram sometimes a certain width can show a space between the divs.

Try to change:

```
width: 85px;
```

To

```
width: 86px;
```

Usually the odd numbers will show a space between the divs try to always use an even number while choosing the width of an element.

Comment: That fixes the problem when the site is displayed in 100%. When you zoom out to 70%, you will still see space every 2nd or 3rd div. Althought, that's a good enough solution for me. Thank you! :)

Comment: Incorrect answer. On a different web browser, at a different resolution, the issue will appear again, so @Krøsh, do not use this as a solution.

Comment: You can use `margin-left: -1px;` and that should do it

Comment: OP already suggested in the question that a negative margin could fix it.